# Continuous function on $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let's say:

$y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,...)\in l^\infty$

$f(y)=(y_1, y_2-y_1, y_3-y_2-y_1,...)$

How can I show that f is continuous for something *like* this? The traditional definition of continuity doesn't apply, does it?

Comment: What norm are you using in the co-domain? Surely, $f((1,1,1,1,\ldots)) \notin l^\infty$.

Comment: Recommended reading :Any introduction to normed linear spaces and Banach spaces.  E.g. Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis, by Simmons.

Comment: @Ingix my codomain was supposed to be $l^\infty$ but I see how the example doesnt work. I just pulled it out of the air. Any example would do, I just want an application of the definition.

Comment: @DainelWainfleet Thanks, I'll give that resource a good read